# C++ storing an element of a string array into a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am currently coding in C++ and am fairly new to it. I am running into issues with converting an element of an array of strings into a variable. The cout statement dcity[selection-1] works as intended. However, I am unable to store dcity[selection-1] into a variable named departureLocation. Visual Studios gives me the error that there is no suitable conversion function from a string to a char. Does anyone have advice on how to properly store this? Thanks!

```
int main()
{

int selection = 0;
char departureLocation;


std::string dcity[] = { "Seattle Detroit Seattle Chicago Houston Seattle" };
std::cout << "Please choose a number from the list";
std::cin >> selection;
std::cout << dcity[selection-1];


departureLocation=dcity[selection-1]

};
```

Comment: You want a vector of strings.

Comment: @NeilButterworth There is no evidence in the code shown that a `std::vector` is better suited for the intended purpose than an array.

Comment: I really like the way you are trying to write your program a bit at a time, instead of writing everything at once. Just don't fall into the trap of thinking that because your program compiles it's going to work. Write a small bit of code, get it to compile, test it and fix any bugs. Only then repeat.

Comment: @Swordfish Vectors are almost always preferable to arrays, because they carry their size around with them, and thus can easily be passed as function parameters.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Since the array of cities one can depart from is unlikely to change during runtime I'd rather suggest `std::array<std::string>` or ``std::array<char const *>`.

Comment: @Swordfish On the contrary, many, many things (in fact most things) change at runtime.  In the case of an airline application, airports can close or open, or be subject to transient special offers, etc. Anyway, that doesn't alter the fact that if you pass a vector to a function, the function knows the size of the vector, but that is not so for arrays, which was my point. I do wonder, when you say things like this,  if you have ever written a large C++ application.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I wrote my comment keeping in mind that boodaloo1s program is most likely one of a beginner learning C++ and won't be used in a scenario where "airports can close or open, or be subject to transient special offers, etc". "if you pass a vector to a function, the function knows the size of the vector, but that is not so for arrays, which was my point." `std::array` knows its size.

Comment: @Swordfish  std::arrays don't carry their size with them - they only have one size - just like C-style arrays. I have no idea why you are so opposed to the idea of using vectors, which is cleaner, simpler, easier, better etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++ is a strongly-typed language, it doesn't like type mismatches.
You've declare your variable in the following way:

`char departureLocation;`

This means departureLocation is a variable of type char, or a single character. So 'C' can go into departureLocation but "Chicago" cannot, as it is more that one character.

You've also declared your array like so:

`std::string dcity[] =`

Here, you have defined the type of the array as std::string. So elements of the array are strings, not chars.

The short answer is that you need to change the type of departureLocation to a string when you declare it, instead of a char. Something like:

`std::string departureLocation;`

I also didn't see any include statements in your code above. For C++ to recognize the string class, you'll need to make sure the following is at the top of your code somewhere:

`#include <string>`

Comment: In addition to the problems that are mentioned above, it's pretty clear that when you wrote this `std::string dcity[] = { "Seattle Detroit Seattle Chicago Houston Seattle" };` what you really should have written is this `std::string dcity[] = { "Seattle", "Detroit", "Seattle", "Chicago", "Houston", "Seattle" };` Strings don't automaticaly split on spaces, you need to write multiple strings separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

`dcity` is an array of `std::string`s. `departureLocation` is a `char` which can only hold one character. To store (copy) an element of the array `dcity`, `departureLocation` must be of type `std::string` (or any other type that can be constructed fron a `std::string`):

```
std::string dcity[] = { "Seattle Detroit Seattle Chicago Houston Seattle" };
std::string departureLocation = dcity[0];
```

Be aware thet `dcity` is an array consisting of only one element. Maybe you want an array where each city is a seperate array element:

```
std::string dcity[] = { "Seattle", "Detroit", "Seattle",
                        "Chicago", "Houston", "Seattle" };
std::string departureLocation = dcity[2];
```

> ```
> std::cin >> selection;
> std::cout << dcity[selection-1];
> ```

Also you should do some error checking before using user input as an array index:

```
if (!(std::cin >> selection) || selection < 1 || selection > sizeof(dcity) / sizeof(*dcity)) {
    std::cerr << "Input error!\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
std::string departureLocation = dcity[selection - 1];
```

If you don't need independent copies of your array elements you could also use a reference to `std::string`:

```
std::string &departureLocation = dcity[selection - 1];
```

Be aware that changes to the string using `departureLocation` will now reflect on the array element `departureLocation` references. If you don't want to allow changes, use a `const` reference:

```
std::string const &departureLocation = dcity[selection - 1];
```

Comment: It's an array of _one_ string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the compiler thinks that there is only one element in the array because arrays in c++ should have commas between each element and each string must be enclosed inside double quotes.The second error is that you are trying to save data of type string into a variable having data type char.

**Code**

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

int selection=0;
string depaturelocation;
string dcity[]={"Seattle","Detroit","Seattle","Chicago","Houstan","Seattle"};
int size=sizeof(dcity)/sizeof(dcity[0]);
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
   cout<<i+1<<" : "<<dcity[i]<<endl;
}
cout<<"please enter the destination no:";
cin>>selection;

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if(selection-1==i)
    {
        depaturelocation=dcity[i];
    }
}
cout<<"destination:"<<depaturelocation;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to write a loop to perform the assignment to `depaturelocation`

Comment: Yeah it's not necssary, you can directly assign value to depaturelocation

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs little modification. 
1. An array is initialized by giving its component values separated by a comma. Note each individual element should be of the same type as that of the declared array. 
2. The C++ is very strict with the type matching. We can assign objects only of the same type. In the above code, a string object is being assigned to a character variable which is against the rule. A C string is an array of characters terminated by null character (\0). In C++, string is more advanced and it is an object which has very useful member function. For e.g. to get length of the string, just say obj.length(). We need to have character array since in string there can be more than one char element. We need to have c-string of the string object to get into an array of characters. Please see below the modified code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    //std::  is not required in front of cout 
int main()
{
    int selection = 0;

    string dcity[] = { "Seattle", "Detroit" ,"Seattle", "Chicago", "Houston","Seattle" };
    cout << "Please choose a number from the list";
    cin >> selection;
    cout << dcity[selection-1] << endl;

    char departureLocation[dcity[selection-1].length()+1];
    strcpy(departureLocation,dcity[selection-1].c_str());
    cout << departureLocation;
   // cout << *c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use C strings when there is no benefit using them. Also there is no such thing as variable length arrays in C++.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But can you explain why C strings should not be used when there is no major benefit. And I did not say anything regarding variable length arrays in my post.

Comment: "And I did not say anything regarding variable length arrays in my post." You did use them: "`char departureLocation[dcity[selection-1].length()+1];`"

Comment: Variable length Arrays are allowed by extension in some compilers, but the results can be unfortunate. They break the compile-time behaviour of `sizeof` for example. Prefer to use a `vector`.

Answer (score -1):

You could to store the selection in a std::string, because char can only store a single character. Be also careful of where you access your array to not go out of bounds (what happens if somebody enters 1000 etc.) and that non-programmer users index lists starting with 1. You can try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const auto Cities = { "Seattle", "Detroit", "Seattle", "Chicago", "Houston", "Seattle" };
    std::cout << "Please choose a number from the list (1-" << Cities.size() << "): ";

    int selection = 0;
    std::cin >> selection;
    if (selection < 1 || selection > Cities.size()) {
        std::cout << "\ninvalid selection!\n";
        return -1;
    }

    const std::string departureLocation = *(Cities.begin() + selection - 1);
    std::cout << "\nyou selected: " << departureLocation;

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I can't be certain, but I suspect the downvotes are because you changed more of the asker's code than you explained. Unexplained code leads to cutting and pasting and Cargo Cult behaviour where programmers imitate what you are doing without understanding why they are doing it.